# How to use - within like '%'% query

Tags: sql-server, date, where-clause, wildcard, sql-like

I have a table column in SQL 2012 called `transitiontime` that contains dates and times in the format `2017-02-02 21:00:34.847`. I'm trying to query all results within the last 3 months, which I would think would just require me to look for `2017-02`, or something to that effect. However if I leave the hyphen in, the query fails.

Examples:

```
WHERE transitiontime like '%2017%' <- works but returns all values from this year

WHERE transitiontime like '%2017-02%' <- Does not work at all

WHERE transitiontime like '%2017%02%' <- Works but pulls in anything with 2017 and 02 in it, even if 02 is just in the time.
```

I would love to get the past 3 months in one query, but right now I'd like to just be able to pull from 1 month.

Comment: What is the data type of the `transitiontime` column?

Comment: Your data isn't what you think it is.  hyphen isn't a special character for purposes of LIKE.   Post a script that reproduces the problem, if you can.  Otherwise this "issue" doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work at all?  Does it return an error, does it return the incorrect data, etc?

Comment: Data type of the transitiontime column is datetime.

Comment: Not sure how to post a script. Do you mean the full query?

Comment: By "doesn't work at all" I mean it doesn't return any information. The query actually says it completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming, since you are using the keyword "like", that the field "transitiontime" is a char oder varchar field?

Change the type of the field to DateTime and use the following query, to get all results for the last three months (applying to SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE transitiontime >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed. It worked.